# Text in the left margin

Tags: margins

I am creating lecture notes, and I want to use a few characters in the left-hand margin to denote:

- Q a question for the students
- PROB a problem I work out
- DEMO a demonstration.

While `\marginpar` gives my desired effect in the right-hand margin, `\reversemarginpar` does not place the text in the left-hand margin but but simply left-justifies it.

How can I get text protruding into the left-hand margin?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\setlength{\parindent}{0cm} % No indentations -- just to be sure
\begin{document}
Using marginpar.

\marginpar{Q:}How many $in^2$ in a $yd^2$?

Good, we see Q: on the right hand side. Now lets see if we can get it on the Left Hand Side (LHS) by using reversemarginnote.

\reversemarginpar{Q:}How many $in^2$ in a $yd^2$?

While it is on the LHS, it doesn't penetrate the margin.  Hopefully marginnote will come through.

\marginnote{Q:}How many $in^2$ in a $yd^2$?
\end{document}
```

[image: Photo Example]

Comment: Please have a look on the [marginnote](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) package and its `\marginnote` command

Comment: `\reversemarginpar` does place the text in the left-hand margin. Please provide a minimal working example (**MWE**) to support your claim.

Comment: `\reversemarginpar` is a *declararation* and does not take an argument.  Subsequent to the declaration, `\marginpar{}` invocations will appear on the left.  The other point worth mentioning is that you should not use it as the first thing of a paragraph...if you do, you should `\leavevmode` first, or else the `\marginpar` appears on the wrong line.

Comment: Based on my above comment, `\reversemarginpar{Q:}` should be replaced with `\leavevmode\reversemarginpar\marginpar{Q:}`.